# MS Word / VBA - how can I loop through the document and look for 2 strings to remove everything in between them?

Tags: string, vba, loops, ms-word

I have an exported MS Word document that I have to clean up and looking for some VBA or high level just the detail code(s) to perform the following:

I have text like:

REPORT HEADERThe cat in the hat has a bat. xxxxx yyy sss zz asss
dsad sadsa ad ad ad as das ad ad sa dad aBEST PRACTICE

What I want to do is for each time I find REPORT HEADER & BEST PRACTICE, want to remove everything in between (or as well as REPORT HEADER)

I understand how to do this within a string (find location of R in REPORT HEADER) and then location right before BEST PRACTICE but how do I do that within a Word document?

Thanks all in advance for any help.

Comment: You shall consult VBA documentation and give it a try. If you're having an issue or are stuck with your code you may come back and post your concrete question.

Comment: I figured out the solution (or work around.) What I ended up doing since the entire section is within a paragraph was to look for the ending string and just put a paragraph break right before it, then I just searched for the paragraphs with the beginning string and removed the entire paragraph.

Comment: okay i cant figure out how to include the code in stackoverflow... until then if you need it i guess there is a way to contact me.

Answer (score 0):

Start Find-Replace feature of MS Word. In **Find field** put the following:

```
(REPORT HEADER)(*)(BEST PRACTICE)
```

in **Replace field** put the following:

```
\1 \3
```

if you want to keep REPORT HEADER BEST PRACTICE, or

```
\3
```

if you want to keep BEST PRACTICE only.

**enable wildcard** on the checkbox list.

Start Find-Replace by pressing appropriate button.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ended up using a for loop with the paragraph object and compared the first part to match my text, if so then I just did a Paragraph.Range.Delete within the loop to remove the entire thing. KISS principle is the way to go!